# Question about the definition of subbasis.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{S}_{1}$ be the collection of all circles in the plane which have their centres on
the $X$-axis. If $\mathcal{S}_{1}$ is a subbasis for a topology $\mathcal{T}_{1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, describe the open sets in
($\mathbb{R}^{2}$,$\mathcal{T}_{1}$):

Let $\mathcal{S}_{2}$ be the collection of all straight lines in the plane which are parallel to
the $X$-axis. If $\mathcal{S}_{2}$ is a subbasis for a topology $\mathcal{T}_{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, describe the open sets in
($\mathbb{R}^{2}$,$\mathcal{T}_{2}$):

I got confused with the definition of subbasis.Does the finite intersection means the new intersection must come from at least two different  sets？ For a element $A$ of a subbasis $\mathcal{S}$.Is A itself  of a intersection of $A\cap A$? If it's not allowed then ($\mathbb{R}^{2}$,$\mathcal{T}_{2}$) only has two open sets they are $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\emptyset$.

and ($\mathbb{R}^{2}$,$\mathcal{T}_{1}$) is a topology space whose open set is symmetric to the X-axis.

If it's allowed then the open set of  ($\mathbb{R}^{2}$,$\mathcal{T}_{2}$) is a uion of straight line parallel to the X-axis.But ($\mathbb{R}^{2}$,$\mathcal{T}_{1}$) is the same.

I don't know which comprehend is right.

Comment: @Antoine: what does countable have to do with anything? Any *union* of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal S_1$ is open...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for given topology $\mathcal{T}$ iff the collection of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{S}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}$. As @dfeuer says, 1-intersection is also finite intersection and if empty-intersection is allowed (so it's whole space), then any $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis of some topology (namely the coarsest topology such that all members of $\mathcal{S}$ are open).

For $(\mathbb{R^2}, \mathcal{T_2})$, you're right. $\mathcal{S_2}$ is actually a basis and open are exactly unions of lines paralel to X-axis.

However $\mathcal{T_1}$ has basis $\{\{(x, y), (x, -y)\}: x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$ so it's “almost discrete”. Open are exactly the sets which are symetric with respect to X-axis.

Answer (score 1):

A set with only one element is a finite set, so if $U\in\mathcal S_1$ then $U = \bigcap\{U\} \in \mathcal S_1$. To be more direct, a "finite intersection" does *not* have to be of two or more elements. In fact, some texts will, in this context, define an empty intersection, $\bigcap\varnothing$, to be "the whole space", whenever it's clear what that means.